# Decrease value from a column in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, c#-4.0, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with 3 columns, like this:

```
| Product | AvailableBooks | TotalBooks |
=========================================
|  Book1  |      12        |      20    |
|  Book2  |      32        |      40    |
|  Book3  |      4         |      19    |
```

I want when I press a button to decrease with -1 value from AvailableBooks, from selected row and save it in database. How can I do this? Be aware! I use a DBML (BindingSource, BindingList, etc.)  for connection with a database!!

Program.cs

```
static class Program
    {
        public static ERALibraryDC _dc = new ERALibraryDC();

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
          //CODE
        }
    }
```

frmMain.cs

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        BindingSource _bsMain = new BindingSource();
        BindingList<Book> _blBooks;
        List<Book> _listOfBooks = new List<Book>();
        User loggedUser;    
        private bool _wasClicked = false;

        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitControls();
        }

        public frmMain(User loggedUser)
        {
            this.loggedUser = loggedUser;
            InitializeComponent();
            InitControls(); 
        }

        public void InitControls()
        {
            dgBooks.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            _listOfBooks = Program._dc.Books.ToList();
            _blBooks = new BindingList<Book>(_listOfBooks);
            _bsMain.DataSource = _blBooks;
            dgBooks.DataSource = _bsMain;
            dgBooks.Refresh();          

            if (loggedUser.IsAdmin == false)
            {
                btnRefresh.Visible = false;
                btnAdd.Visible = false;
                btnEdit.Visible = false;
                btnDelete.Visible = false;
                btnHistory.Visible = false;
                btnSave.Visible = false;

                CTotalBooksCopies.Visible = false;
                cDeleted.Visible = false;
            }
        }   

        private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dgBooks.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            _listOfBooks = Program._dc.Books.ToList();
            _blBooks = new BindingList<Book>(_listOfBooks);
            _bsMain.DataSource = _blBooks;
            dgBooks.DataSource = _bsMain;
            dgBooks.Refresh();
        }

        private void btnRentBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(CTotalBooksAvailable)!= 0)
            {
                while (Convert.ToInt32(CTotalBooksAvailable) != 0)
                {
                    int min;
                    min = Convert.ToInt32(CTotalBooksAvailable) - 1;

                    dgBooks.Columns[3].ValueType = min;             
                }
                    frmRentBook rentBook = new frmRentBook();
                    rentBook.Show();

                    Rental newRental = new Rental();
                    newRental.RentedDate = DateTime.Today;
                    newRental.DateToReturn = DateTime.Today.AddDays(30);
                    newRental.User = loggedUser.DisplayName;

                    //foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dgBooks.Rows)
                    //  {           
                    //          int n = rentBook.dgRentBook.Rows.Add();
                    //          rentBook.dgRentBook.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    //          rentBook.dgRentBook.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item.Cells[1].Value.ToString();                
                    //  }

                    //  Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.
                    // newRental.Name = Convert.ToString(dgBooks.Rows.Add(cBookTitle));
                    //   newRental.Author = Convert.ToString(dgBooks.Rows.Add(cAuthor));

                    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

                    rentBook.dgRentBook.Refresh();
                    Program._dc.Rentals.InsertOnSubmit(newRental);
                    Program._dc.SubmitChanges();

                    rentBook._listOfRentals = Program._dc.Rentals.ToList();
                    rentBook._bsRental.DataSource = rentBook._listOfRentals;
                    rentBook.dgRentBook.DataSource = rentBook._bsRental;
                    rentBook.dgRentBook.Refresh();
                    rentBook._bsRental.ResetBindings(false);

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The book will be again on library soon!");
            }
        }


        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            Program._dc.SubmitChanges();
        }

        private void btnHistory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmRentBook rentBook = new frmRentBook();
            rentBook.Show();
        }   

    }
}
```

Comment: It would be best to show the code that deals with the database in this regard. There are numerous ways to use a database for this, so without knowing the method involved, we couldn't give you any specific advice.

Comment: @CharlesMay I use a DBML: BindingSource, BindingList :)

Answer (score -1):

Solved my problem!

I add this on my button and every time when I press it, will decrease with -1 value from column:

Book b = _bsMain.Current as Book;
b.TotalBooksAvailable--;